# Phone only charged while plugged into PC

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop, android, phone

I just plugged a Redmi 8 to my laptop and nothing happened but charging. It's a Mi notebook which is have two USB-A ports. Anything had worked no problem a couple days ago.

The 1st port not detect my phone while the 2nd did (the 2nd port worked without problem).
What I've tried on this 1st port:

- Tried another phone: not worked
- Tried another device (USB flash drive, keyboard, mouse, remote, ...): Worked
- Clean dust: not worked
- Connect via a USB hub (plugged a USB hub into this port then plugged in my phone into this USB hub): worked

Also, I tried

- Turn off and turn on (both phone and pc): not worked
- Uninstall and reinstall driver: not worked
- Update windows: not worked
- Googled: nothing worked
- Config in developer option to change default USB configuation to file transfer: not worked

*Not worked meaning they've not showed USB option so I cannot change it behavior between only charging or files transfer or else.

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB cable?

Comment: @Robert I did, just like the current one it's worked on the other port but not this port.

Comment: Are you sure the port is a full USB port? Some devices have charge-only ports, often those ports have a different color like green.

Comment: Even if this port is charge only, why it work with other devices but not the phone? On the other hands, there are only 1 charge port and that port can transfer data, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I'm trying to change autoplay setting from take no action to ask me everytime and now my phone can connect with all USB ports.

But I don't know why only 1 USB port not worked because of this autoplay policy.

My phone had linked with PC earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips that might help you
Try to connect Android devices to PC directly instead of through USB hub.
Restart your phone and connect to PC while in Airplane mode.
Remove battery and SIM card, and wait a while, then put them back and restart.
Lastly, if still not connected, the USB socket in your PC may be faulty.

Comment: Yes I did, execpt remove battery because it need to dissemble my phone (laptop too)